# Can I save an object to the app.config file?

Tags: c#, application-settings

I need to use a config file for my application which will save a list of details for each entity:
for example-

```
<person A>
         <name= >
         <age= >
<person B>
         <name=>
         <age= >
```

is something of this sort possile in the settings class or this requires using the app.config file wihtout the settings class wrapper?

Edit: My application used to have a single entity, now it should support multiple entities and therefore save multiple entities in  some config.

Comment: But why do you want to store it as a .config? Have you considered using an ordinary XML file?

Comment: Since I want the API of the settings. and I want it to be generated and named with the applicaiton name- i.e. an application configuration file which this is exactly what it is

Comment: A rephrase of the question - could a values of the settings file contain a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can save any sort of information (strings) in .config file. You'd then use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to access the saved information by using a Key.

But why would you want to save information like this in the .config?

I recommend you use an XML document for this purpose. You can then use the XDocument class to parse it.

**Edit:**

After reading your comment, I think the app.config file cannot save an object. So you could **not** save a class object there.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't use <![CDATA[ ... ]]> and put an xml-serialized object (or possibly another simple serializer) in there then deserialize it later (unless someone else knows better?

Comment: @Brad: I didn't know you could do that. So essentially you'd serialize a class and save some voodoo string?

Comment: That's the plan, stan. Again, not sure if it _can_, I just don't see why it _wouldn't_ (given what I know about XML and storing abstract data within). You could probably create the object and decorate it with XmlNodeAttibute and XmlElementAttribute, serialize it to a file, then push it in to the .config. Worst-case scenario, you use XmlDocument and go down the tree yourself (bypass ConfigurationManager) and deserialize the results.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for this purpose. But I still don't see the point of storing it in the .config file. Anyway, you could serialize the object in a XML format and store it in a key that you would add to the .config file, as a string. I guess that would solve it.

If you decide to store it as a simple XML file, use the [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and [XMLNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) classes.

Answer (score 1):

The config file is not a good place to store dynamic configuration information, it's intended for configuring an app, not maintaining state.

Rather use a separate file, or something like a SQLite database to store dynamic data.